# I want to compare the current date with the date inserted in my database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have write this code for it.

```
public function getRecords(){

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->where("('startdate <' NOW())", NULL, FALSE)
                    ->where("('enddate <' NOW())", NULL, FALSE)
                    ->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
       return $query->result();

    }

    }
```

but it is showing warning.

> Warning:
>   include(/home/qpay21/public_html/Cryptofam/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/qpay21/public_html/Cryptofam/system/core/Exceptions.php on line
>   268

Comment: You need to edit the question properly format it so it can be read clearly.

Comment: i Have to compare the date that i have store in my datebase with the current timestamp

Comment: I think error you have and code you've shown are entirely different things. Also, the warning message looks perfectly clear to me: you have no such file as `Exceptions.php`.

Comment: Actually `Exceptions.php` is the file generating the error. The path to this is wrong `/home/qpay21/public_html/Cryptofam/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php`.

Comment: so can i know how i can compare my datebase date with current timestamp?

Comment: Try changing the path on line 268 in `Exceptions.php` to `../../application/views/errors/html/error_php.php` maybe that will solve the problem. I don't actually know where `error_php.php` is so it's hard to guess the correct path

Comment: where is your table name?

Comment: Please always use the preview window before posting questions. Additionally, if you can take a few minutes to learn the formatting tools - in particular block formatting for code - that would help us enormously. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the get you need to specify your table name as well

Try:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //now will be equal to the exact second its executed, 
//$now = date('Y-m-d'); //equal to today

return  $this->db->select('*')
            ->where('startdate <', $now)
            ->where('enddate <', $now)
            ->get('name_of_table')->result();
```